# Stacked Bar type of jquery Highcharts with data from HTML Table

Tags: jquery, highcharts, stackedbarseries

is there anyone have tried to use highcharts jquery with stacked bar like this one http://highcharts.com/demo/bar-stacked

in that example, the data series was from an array, 
now i want it to get the data from html table like this http://highcharts.com/demo/column-parsed

as for that example, i have tried it for a normal bar and column, it was a success, but for the stacked bar, i don't know what should i do :(
i'am still new for this highcharts, so maybe anyone can help me?? o.O
thx..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `stacking` parameter to `series` in `plotOptions`:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        stacking: 'normal'
    }
}
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/7Mmee/10676/